# Does a user have permissions to write outside /home/userDir?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, users, root, non-root-user

Does a *normal** user have permissions to write anywhere else than his own home dir? (no `sudo` and those privilege escalation tools)

I say *normal* because I do not know more categories than root and *normal*. Let say the involved user installed the system and do the administrative things with `sudo <command>`.

**I use Ubuntu, by the way.**

Thanks.

Comment: `/usr/local` in Debian is owned by the `staff` group. Being a member of staff is perhaps not entirely normal, but it isn't anything like being a superuser either.

Comment: Thanks, that is interesting, I added the detail in the question explaining that I use Ubuntu

Comment: ubuntu is debian based Linux distribution, but as I tried to explain in my comment below, by default, a newly created user doesn't get membership to `staff` group. It is something the sysadmin should deliberately grant to the user.

Comment: Yes, of course a newly created user does not get membership to the `staff` group. I never suggested that was the case. However, membership in `staff` is a relatively minor privilege, as far as I can tell. I do not have documentation confirming this, but as far as I know, the only thing membership in `staff` gets you is the ability to write to `/usr/src`.

Comment: Is there some reason that simply browsing around and checking the permissions wasn't an option for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. The normal/unprivileged user can write to `/tmp` and `/var/tmp`, for legitimate reasons. Also, if the user or group permissions of a given file/directory includes those of the user, he or she can write to those files or directories as well.

Having said that, providing write capability to operating system files and directories to a normal user, is shooting one's self at the foot, as best as an analogy goes. There is a lot to say about this but this is not the place. If you are curious about *why ?* I suggest searching for and reading articles about "UNIX/Linux system administration best practices".

Comment: Thanks, I see, but "by default"  is the normal user in some of those groups able to write outside the home?

Comment: On linux, when you create a *normal* user, it gets created with a new group, which is equal to user's name. Say, for me, it would be `mel:mel`. Unless `root` makes an explicit ownership or permission change on any directory, this user is not able to write to any other place than his/her home directory and `/tmp` and `/var/tmp`

Comment: That's perfectly clear, so, that is the behavior for pure Linux. Do you know if Ubuntu does some other change?

Comment: not that I know of.

Comment: @Faheem has commented in the question something about that in Debian.

Comment: That is a `staff` group membership. A newly created user doesn't get automatically added to that group. It is something the root user should explicitly do. I just tested on my ubuntu 14 server on Amazon EC2 cloud and result was as expected.

Answer (score 5):

`/tmp` and possibly `/var/tmp` are writtable to any users.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/127071)

Comment: Also /run/shm  for example

Comment: @PersianGulf: This is actually the minimal answer to the literal question.  It doesn't expand on any of the issues about why this is good or bad.  It could be a comment, but it's actually valid as an answer.